# Kendo grid returning only one record

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I´ve been searching all over the net to find an answer to this problem but with no success, my problem is with my Kendo ui grid which is returning just one record. The funny thing is, i have another grids that are returning all the records correctly, so i simply using the same code but there´s got be a detail that is escaping me so i was hopping someone could point on that, this is the code i´m using (CRUD):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: 
        {
          read:  
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php",      
            },

          update: 
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php?type=update",
              type:"POST",
              complete: function(e) 
              {  
                $("#gridClientes").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
              }
            },

          destroy: 
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php?type=destroy",
              type: "POST"
            },

          create: 
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php?type=create",
              type: "POST",
              complete: function (e) {
                $("#gridClientes").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            }

            },

            parameterMap: function(options, operation) 
            {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) 
                {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            }                      
        },

        error:function(e)
        {
          console.log(e);
          //alert(e.message);
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 8,
        schema: 
        {
          data: "data",
            total: function(response) 
            {
              return $(response.data).length;
            },
            model: 
            {
              id: "idCliente",

              fields: 
              {
                idCliente: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "number"},
                titulo: { validation: { required: false } },
                primeiroNome: { validation: { required: true } },
                ultimoNome: { validation: { required: true } },
                morada: { validation: { required: false } },
                codigoPostal: { type: "string",validation: { required: false} },
                cidade: { validation: { required: false } },
                pais: { validation: { required: false } },
                estado: { validation: { required: false } },
                telefone: { type: "string", validation: { required: false, min: 1} },
                email: { validation: { required: false } },
                passaporte: { validation: { required: false } },
                bi: { type: "number", validation: { required: false} },
                foto: { type: "string", validation: { required: false} },
                comentarios: { validation: { required: false } },
                NomeUtilizadorCriador: {editable: true,validation: { required: false } },
                DataCriacao: {editable: false,  validation: { required: false } },
                NomeUtilizadorUpdate: {editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                DataUpdate: {editable: false,  validation: { required: false } },
              }
           }
        }
      });

      $("#gridClientes").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: dataSource,            
          height: 550,
          serverPaging: true,
          pageable  : true,
          toolbar:[{name: "create",text: $varGridQuartosBtnNovoPT},{name: "close",text: "X"}],
          editable  : {mode : "popup",               
            window : {title: "Editar",}
          },
          columns: [
                  { field: "titulo", title: "Título", width: "8px", },
                  { field: "primeiroNome", title: "Primeiro Nome", width: "14px" },
                  { field: "ultimoNome", title: "Ultimo Nome", width: "14px" },
                  { field: "morada", title: "Morada", width: "11px" },
                  { field: "cidade", title: "Cidade", width: "11px" },
                  { field: "codigoPostal", title: "CEP", width: "9px", editor:numberEditor },
                  { field: "pais", title: "País", width: "14px" ,editor: paisEditor},
                  { field: "estado", title: "Estado", width: "10px", hidden: true },
                  { field: "telefone", title: "Telefone", width: "12px",editor:numberEditor},
                  { field: "email", title: "Email", width: "17px" },
                  { field: "passaporte", title: "Passaporte", width: "15px", hidden: true },
                  { field: "bi", title: "Bi", width: "10px", hidden: true ,editor:numberEditor},
                  { field: "foto", title: "Foto", hidden: true, editor:fotoEditor},
                  { field: "comentarios", title: "Comentários", hidden: true, editor: textareaEditor},
                  { field: "NomeUtilizadorCriador", title: "Criado por", hidden: true,editor:numberEditor},
                  { field: "DataCriacao", title: "Criado em", hidden: true, width: "10px"},
                  { field: "NomeUtilizadorUpdate", title: "Atualizado por", hidden: true, editor:numberEditor},
                  { field: "DataUpdate", title: "Atualizado em", hidden: true, width: "10px"},
                  {command:[{ text: "Detalhes", click: showDetails },{ name: "edit",text:"Editar"},{ name: "destroy",text:"Apagar"}],title:"&nbsp;",width: "30px"}],

});
```

If my database is empty and i insert just one record, then it returns that record correctly, but if i hit the new button to insert another record, **it inserts in the database** but the kendo grid returns/displays nothing, Meanwhile i have discovered a difference between this kendogrid and the others(that are working correctly) when i open the chrome console, this one returns two objects "data":

```
0: {,…}
data: {0: "70", 1: "", 2: "jonh", 3: "sousa", 4: "", 5: "", 6: "", 7: "", 8: "", 9: "", 10: "", 11: "",…}

1: {,…} 
data: {0: "73", 1: "", 2: "joana", 3: "banana", 4: "", 5: "", 6: "", 7: "", 8: "", 9: "", 10: "", 11: "",…}
```

the other kendogrids, only return one object data, why? i do not know because i´m using the same code. I thought it could be something related with my .php file, but then if it was, it shouldn´t even insert one record right?.

I also have this error when i call the grid:

```
Object {xhr: Object, status: "parsererror", errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, sender: ht.extend.init, _defaultPrevented: false…}
```

this error appears when my database is empty. If i have one record, then the erro disappears and as i said before the grid displays correctly, BUT the error returns if i insert another record.

Sorry for the long post, thanks for your time, any help would be very appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You can always use [schema.parse](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) to check the data the grid is recieving. But its strange that your response has two distinct objects with the same name. Maybe the grid isn't(and it isn't really suposed to) understand it. Anyway, I think the case of the insert works have nothing to do with the problem of the reading the request data.

Comment: Thanks for answering my post, i never used schema.parse before but i went to the docs and try to make it work, but the thing is i´m stuck..i just don´t understand what i´m missing here. I have the exact same tables for other purposes and they work just fine, that´s why i´m thinking it could be my .php file but the way i´m loading data is equal to the others.

Comment: Well, then show how you generate the data to send to the grid in your php file.

Comment: hey guys, sorry for the late answer, my problem was on my php file, i was not encoding the data correctly, i was using this: $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and i should be using this: $result = $statement->fetchAll();.

Comment: i´m what? did not understand.